# zend framework 2 Reconnect to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework2

I've got a MVC Skeleton Application with my own Module. 
My Controller converts PDF Files into Jpgs.
If the script not run more than 10 Minutes everything is ok. But if it takes longer, I get the Error "MySQL Server has gone away". I tried to lift the mysql wait time up, but it's on a shared Webspace. So I have no Chance for that.

My Controller gets the database Connection from my application. But if the script arrives  the model, it's gone away.

Maybe I'm too stupid, but I can't find a way to reconnect the database from the Controller or the model.

Does anybody know a solution?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Check you mysql server timed out and closed the connection.

To fix, check your **wait_timeout** mysql variable in your my.cnf configuration.